# google authentication pop up not working using firebase in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-signin

while doing a project...i did an authentication with google account.
but its not working

i used firebase for authentication,  when i click on the button...nothing is showing..

the firebase code is given below

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
 export const auth= firebase.auth();
 export const firestore=firebase.firestore();
 
 const provider=new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
 provider.setCustomParameters({prompt:'select_account'});
 export const signInWithGoogle=()=>auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

 export default firebase;
```

and the calling code is

```
<CustomButton type='submit'> SIGN IN</CustomButton>
<CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle}> SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE</CustomButton>
```

BUT both button behave the same..it showing required email...no popup is showing when i click the ssign in with google

custom button is a react component

please help

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem: the popup shown up, but nothing loaded. I fixed it by adding the `onSubmit:{this.handleSubmit}` properties to tag `<form>` with

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ email: ' ', password: ' ' });
}
```